# Does Dynamic DNS update accept only few record types?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have looked on google, but still unclear about this question. Does dynamic DNS on linux only accept few record types or all records such as SOA, A, PTR, MX?

Comment: That would depend entirely on how you're implementing DDNS.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M lets assume we do basic configuration with a forward and reverse lookup zone with a single primary DNS server.

Comment: With what DNS server? With what DDNS method? With what DDNS agent? Is it internal or public? Can you use DHCP to push updates? Do you require DNSSEC? If you're actually trying to solve a problem, you need to provide WAY more information to make this question answerable with any hope of precision.

Comment: You should probably start by describing the problem you've encountered. What led you to asking this question?

Comment: I don't have any problem, it is just for concept to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the "on linux" part of your questions, since it makes no sense, the answer is a clear no. DNS UPDATE as described in [RFC2136](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2136.txt) supports adding, deleting and editing of all record types.